# Angular2 - router-outlet with login structure

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm building angular2 app and currently I have an home component with navbar, toolbar and router-outlet for the main content.
I want to add one extra page for the login mechanism, so if the user is not authenticated the login page will be displayed in the entire screen and after login to user will be navigated to the component with the structure above.

How can I manage this structure? Do I need two router outlets? the first one for the navigation between login and home pages and one for the main content in the home page?
Any other common structure which is more simple than two router outlets?

Comment: any luck with the answer below?

Comment: I still miss one thing, the base application page includes router-outlet with shows the login component if no user is signed in or the home component if user signed in, inside the home component I need another router-outlet which changes upon user navigation?

Comment: Ah, I see your question. You should also have a top-level component, call this `App` -- and that's where your `<router-outlet>` should go. Check out this article re: top-level components: https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-your-first-angular-2-components

Comment: any luck with the above link?

Comment: I am in need of the same requirements, do you have this working? can you please share more info in case if you are able to implement the same?

Comment: Hey @Krishnan , I solved this issue and posted here an answer with my implementation. feel free to comment if something is not 100% clear and I'll update my answer.

Comment: @galvan, appreciate your reply, but can you please add some sample code as well which would add more clarity in understanding. If possible please showcase your routeconfig(s) and the placing of router-outlets etc. thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I succeed achieving this workflow by implementing this structure.
I have two main components:

LoginComponent which it's route is '/login'.
HomeComponent which it's route is ''. (empty route).

In addition I set a guard for my HomeComponent which checks if the user is authenticated in his canActivate. If no I navigates the user to the '/login' route.

Then in my home component I have template with the following structure:
tool-bar, side-menu, and router-outlet.

The last thing I have to do is to configure other app routes as children routes of my HomeComponent. (for example: '/news' is a child route of '').

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer. I also implemented it this way, and am much happier than my previous (very hacky) solution. I've also nested it two levels deep, so I have my LoginComponent and a Header Component (`path: ''`), Header has a child route for NavigationComponent (also `path: ''`), and that has all of my other child routes. This way, I can have routes that have just the header with no nav, or routes that have both, or none. If I wanted a page that has the header, but no navigation, I would add it as a child of the Header route.

Comment: Could you please point me out to an example where you implemented it?

Comment: @Travesty3 mean have 2 router-outlet

Comment: you dont' need this old techniques, just the tree routers with childs

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I highly recommend utilizing the updated Angular2 router. The newest router includes support for `guards` which are added to your route configuration to prevent access to certain routes.

After ensuring you have the latest router, you'll need to do several things:

1) Create a top-level component and call this `App`. This is where your `<router-outlet>` will go.

2) Create a `Login` component. This component should include a form for logging in to your application, along with the logic for handling login. Create a route for this component.

3) Create a `Home` component (you have already done this).

4) Use a `guard` (new functionality in the latest router) to prevent users from accessing the home component before logging in.

Your code will look something like this (for more info, see: https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/upgrading-to-the-new-angular-2-router-255605d9da26#.n7n1lc5cl)

```
// auth-guard.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  CanActivate,
  Router,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot
} from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from './services/auth/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

For more information on guards:

I would also highly suggest reading up on the latest Angular router (the docs have recently been updated): https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Answer (score 1):

The key is using child routes

```
import { RouterModule, Route } from '@angular/router';

const ROUTES: Route[] = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'notes',
    children: [
      { path: '', component: NotesComponent },
      { path: ':id', component: NoteComponent }
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)
  ]
})
```

see more here
[the-three-pillars-of-angular-routing](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-three-pillars-of-angular-routing-angular-router-series-introduction-fb34e4e8758e)