# Angular2 CLI : Equivalent of run command

Tags: angular

I need to run code before my application completes bootstrapping to ensure they are authenticated. In AngularJs there was the "run" command. I understand I can use a promise to achieve the same result using the Angular2 CLI but cannot find information on how to implement the solution. Does anybody have a simple example/advice?

Many thanks.

Comment: You can use the Guards in Angular2 router in order to protect different routes of you application - allow navigation only if the user is authenticated. Please refer this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38313887/angular2-router-outlet-with-login-structure

Comment: Thanks @galvan Is there no equivalent on run? I wanted to perform some one-off actions on application load.